# JSF application backend architecture with JPA and CDI

Tags: jsf, jpa, architecture, cdi

I'm working on a JSF application with JPA and CDI; I use the following backend architecture:

- Controllers (CDI annotation for JSF process)
- Services (CDI annotations to be injected into Controllers and other Services)
- DAOs (handled with EntityManager)

My question is, how should exactly be EntityManager and transactions be handled?
For example transactions (I don't use EJB or Deltaspike, so no declarative transactions available) should be managed by the Service layer (am I right?), but each data-releated other operation should be handled by the DAOs. So where should EntityManager be injected?

Also, should EntityManager be request (or session or method) scoped?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: You should use the EJB 3 framework, and use one entity manager per unit of work, i.e a stateless entity façade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use *service layer* to manage a business logic and *data access layer* to manage object-relational model. As a consequence of the above, entity manager and transactions should be part of DAO. It's important to keep transactions as short as possible.

The decision which type of scope to choose is not so obvious as it depends on the nature of your bean/application. An example usage followed by [this](http://www.slideshare.net/kelapure/2012-0409v2tdp1167cdibestpracticesfinal) presentation, slide #15:

- `@RequestScoped`: DTO/Models, JSF backing beans
- `@ConversationScoped`: multi-step workflow, Shopping cart
- `@SessionScoped`: User login credentials
- `@ApplicationScoped`: Data shared by entire app, Cache

As you can see a scope of a given bean and the related entity manager is specific for the problem it concerns. If a given bean is *request scoped* its state is preserved for a single HTTP request in the same HTTP session. For a *session scoped* bean the state is maintained through HTTP session. An example approach may look somehow like the following (pseudocode):

```java
@SessionScoped // conversation, application scoped as well
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Inject
    private Dao dao;

    public void createSomething(SomeDto dto) {
        // dto -> entity transformation
        dao.create(entity);
    }

    public SomeDto getSomething(int id) {
        SomeEntity entity = em.findById(id);
        // entity -> dto transformation
        return dto;
    }
}
```

```java
@RequestScoped
@Transactional
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager em; //creating em is cheap

    // TxType.REQUIRED by default
    public void create(SomeEntity entity) { 
        em.persist(entity);
    }

    @Transactional(TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public SomeEntity findById(int id) {
        return em.find(SomeEntity.class, id);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Isn't @Transactional an EJB annotation?

Comment: I would say that `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute` is an EJB annotation and `javax.transaction.Transactional` is a CDI. Since Java EE 7 you can use `@Transactional` interceptor to control transactions in a declarative way for CDI based beans. If you are bound to Java EE 6 you need to create your own interceptor ([an example](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_151_transactional_interceptors_using)).

Comment: If anyone else would like to implement declarative transactions with CDI, here another article: [link](http://smokeandice.blogspot.hu/2009/12/cdi-and-declarative-transactions.html)

Comment: Where should code that checks privileges of currently logged in user be? Or any logic that depends on currently logged in user?

Comment: I would put that code in a service (business) layer. You may then request privileges in a similar way i.e. by requesting LDAP database, etc.